# Kodi Libreelec stuttering playback from NFS share

Tags: debian, nfs, kodi

Infrastructure:

- 1 Fileserver VM on HP DL380e
- 2 Kodi on AndroidTV
- 1 Kodi/Libreelec on RaspberryPi
- 1 Kodi/Libreelec on intel NUC 10th

Libreelec is version 9.2.6.
Kodi is version 18.9

All was running fine and fast - no problems so far.

Yesterday I did an update (apt-get dist-upgrade) on my fileserver (Debian Bullseye).

After the update, playing movies with Kodi from the NFS shares was stuttering and I had jumps and rendering-artifacts.

I tried to reduce NFS-version to version 3 on server, with no result.

Than I mounted the shares with SMB (Kodi-build-in) and (on the intel NUC) NFS manually. With these mounts all runs fine, without hickups, artifacts or what so ever.

I think the problem is Kodi build-in libnfs? Seems to have problem with "newest" NFS-server-version?

Can anyone help?

EDIT:
Seems to be a kernel-problem: https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/issues/19147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From kernel 5.10.11 to 5.10.15 there is a bug.
If you can't wait for the new kernel, build you own.

Here a little documentation with Debian:

```
    apt-get install linux-source-X.XX
    apt-get install libdev libelf-dev libssl-dev m4 debhelper dpkg-dev dwarves
    mkdir ~/kernel
    cd ~/kernel
    tar xavf /usr/src/linux-source-X.XX.tar.xz
    cp /boot/config-X.XX ~/kernel/linux-source-X.XX/.config
    nano ~/kernel/linux-source-X.XX/.config
    ### change CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=""
    ### change #CONFIG_SYSTEM_EXTRA_CERTIFICATE
    
    cd linux-source-X.XX
    make oldconfig
    nano net/sunrpc/svcsock.c
    ### change at nearly row 1113 see link below
    
    make -j 3 deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-yournamehere KDEB_PKGVERSION=$(make kernelversion)-1
    
    cd ..
    dpkg -i linux-image-X.XX-yournamehere-1_amd64.deb
```

Link: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v5.10.15&id=8e081627f3a7f733a4955ee40b385c972f010f05